# Serial Execution of many task with $q

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

Nowadays I am playing with `$q` of super heroic AngularJS. I have three `asynchronous` task. Let's call them `taskA`, `taskB` and `taskC`. I want to execute them one by one. Currently I am using `$q`'s `all()` method. I am doing following:

```
var taskA = function() {
    var d = $q.defer();
    $timeout(function() {
      $log.log('Task A');
      d.resolve('A is done');
    }, Math.random() * 5000);
    return d.promise;
  };


  var taskB = function() {
    var d = $q.defer();
    $timeout(function() {
      $log.log('Task B');
      // d.resolve('B is done');
      d.reject('B is rejected');
    }, Math.random() * 5000);
    return d.promise;
  };


  var taskC = function() {
    var d = $q.defer();
    $timeout(function() {
      $log.log('Task C');
      //d.resolve('C is done');
      d.reject('C is rejected');
    }, Math.random() * 5000);
    return d.promise;
  };

  $scope.startWithAll = function() {
    $log.log('With all started');
    var promises = [taskA(), taskB(), taskC()];
    $q.all(promises).then(
      //success callback...
      function(result) {
        $log.log(result);
      },
      //error callback
      function(error) {
        $log.log(error);
      },
      //progress callback
      function() {
        //todo implement it
      }
    ).finally(function() {
      $log.log('I am from finally');
    });
  };
```

The problem with this approach is that all my tasks are executed in parallel. And in `success` of `then` I get the result of each task in an `array`. If any of the task is rejected then rest of the tasks continue the execution but the error `callback` is executed and I get the error `object` in the callback. What I want to do is that at first only `taskA` should be executed then `taskB` and then `taskC` if any of them is rejected or failed then rest of the task should not be executed. And there execution should not be parallel it should be serial. To to execute them serially I am doing this :

```
$scope.startSerial = function() {
    $log.log('Serially started');
    $q.when().then(function(result) {
      $log.log(result);
      return taskA();
    }).then(function(result) {
      $log.log(result);
      return taskB();
    }).then(function(result) {
      $log.log(result);
      return taskC();
    }).finally(function() {
      $log.log('I am from finally');
    });
  };
```

So this solves my problem. But the thing is that in first `callback` I am getting `undefined`, I don't have any problem with that so we can omit this part. But currently I have only three tasks so this approach is fine but what if tomorrow I have more than three task then this will not be a good way to implement. Is there any other way to do so cause I can not keep on adding multiple `then` just below another. I have created the [plunkr for this](http://plnkr.co/edit/t8PCyp4SdBrIwTwwY1TW?p=preview) . What I am thinking is about creating a `service` which will create this task execution hierarchy but I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a loop, that connects all your promises:

```
  function each(arr, func) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      func(arr[i], i);
    }
  }

  $scope.startSerial = function() {
      var funcs = [taskA, taskB, taskC];
      $log.log('Serially started');
      var s = $q.when();
      each(funcs, function (func) {
          s = s.then(function (result) {
            $log.log(result);
            return func();
          });
      });
      s.finally(function () {
        $log.log('I am from finally');
      });
  }
```

This should result in the same behavior as your original script, but you can simply adjust the array `funcs` instead of adding additional blocks of code for each promise.

Answer (score 1):

You could put the tasks in an array in the order you want them to execute, then loop through them and exit the loop if a task fails. It's not really sexy, but it would get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is super old, but I still had to deal with this recently, and I was originally using a loop.  I then decided to create a recursive method where you pass your array of promises and the current index promise.

```
//However you populate your array
let myPromises = [];

//Start with the first promise, which is a zero index
recursiveFunction(myPromises, 0)
    .finally(function() {
        console.log("all promises done");
    });

function recursiveFunction(promises, promiseIndex) {
    //Make sure your promise index is valid
    if (promiseIndex < 0 || promiseIndex >= promises.length) {
        return $q.reject("invalid index");
    }

    let defer = $q.defer();

    promises[promiseIndex]()
        .finally(function() {
            if (promiseIndex < promises.length - 1) {
                recursiveFunction(promises, ++promiseIndex)
                    .finally(function () {
                        defer.resolve();
                    });
            } else {
                defer.resolve();
            }        
        });

    return defer.promise;
}
```